# How to assign a class template to a declared type?

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on a project to implement a Property Template Class and I need to have the template operate on a private type that I have declared. My Property template code is just

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

template<class T>
  class Property 
    {
      public:
        Property() : m_value() {}
        Property( const T& value ) : m_value(value) {}

        operator const T& () const { return m_value; }

        Property<T>& operator = (const T& value) 
         {
            m_value = value;
            return *this;
          }

        bool operator == (const T& other) const 
          {
            return m_value == other;
          }

        bool operator != (const T& other) const 
          {
            return !(*this == other);
          }

        bool operator < (const T& other) const 
          {
            return m_value < other;
          }

        bool operator > (const T& other) const 
          {
            return other < m_value;
          }

        bool operator <= (const T& other) const 
          {
            return !(other < m_value);
          }

        bool operator >= (const T& other) const 
          {
            return !(m_value < other);
          }

        template<typename U>
          friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Property<U>& property);

      private:
        T m_value;
    };

template<typename T>
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Property<T>& property) 
    {
      os << property.m_value;
      return os;
    }

typedef Property<int> IntProperty;
```

What I am trying to work out is how atttach the template to a type like this so the template works on the i_prop int

```
private:
  int i_prop;

public:
  Property<int> IProp ; //Needs to operate on i_prop
```

Must have looked at least 100 websites on Templates but no answer. I the thought I could just create another constuctor

```
Property( class V& ) : V( m_value ) {}
```

Nope.
Maybe this cannot be done with templates?

OK.

```
private:
    int AInt;
    float AFloat;
    ......

public:
   void iset( int A ) {AInt = A};
   int iget() {return AInt};
   void fset( float A ) { AFloat = A };
   float fget() { return AFloat};
   etc......
```

That is what the template is for it automatically has a set and get for what ever type that is assigned.

```
Property<float> AFloat;
AFloat = 0.0f;
float B = AFloat;
```

Good OOP states that you declare private varibles the have a get set method to read and write them. Who wants to type out a set and get for every private declaration. That is what templates are for.

Comment: Why do you need `Property` at all?

Comment: If `Property` has to refer to a `T` out of it (like `i_prop`), then the `m_value` member must be a refernce or a pointer.

Comment: `//Needs to operate on i_prop`: I do not understand what you want here. I can't make sense of the title or "_how atttach the template to a type_" either. Also, I don't see how templates are relevant here. Suppose instead of `Property` being a template it was just a normal class with `int` instead of `T`. How would your question differ in that case? "_operate on a private type that I have declared_": I don't see a private type anywhere in the code.

Comment: Not sure templates are relevant here. Your question seems to be how do I make a class (templates are classes too) refer to some other entity outside the class. The answer is to use a reference or a pointer. So `m_value` must be a reference or a pointer. Now I think you probably know this, but you wrongly think that templates bring some magic that allows you to 'attach' them in some way to other entities. This is not true.

Comment: Another solution is not to have two entities at all, is there anything wrong with just having `public: Property<int> IProp;`? Do you need `i_prop` as a separate member?

Comment: Why not add another template parameter for passing in a class for the property class to be friends with? This would allow direct access for this class to the value of the property and avoid having to store a reference to the member variable in the property...

Comment: Why do you need `Property` in the first place? It's very hard to implement without memory overhead, and even if we show you how to do that, why can't you access the variable directly?

Comment: The whole point of getters/setters is to be able to add additional logic like checking for valid values in the setter and making the way you store the info independent of the members the used externally (getter+setter). This you cannot do this when using your property type...

Comment: Btw: if you want to go with your property type, I recommend implementing the comparison operators in a way that makes comparison expressions symetric. (Given your implementation e.g. `intProperty == 1` works, but `1 == intProperty` doesn't...)

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer to this question. Regards.

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>

class Property
   {
      public:
        Property( T& initialValue = T() ) : m_value( initialValue ) {}

        operator T() const 
          {
            return get();
          }

        void operator = ( const T& value ) 
          {
            if( m_value != value ) // only call set if the values are different
              set( value );
          }

        T get() const 
          {
            return m_value;
          }

        void set( const T& value ) 
          {
            m_value = value;
          }

      private:
        T& m_value;
    };

class Test 
  {
    private:
      int a_prop;

    public:
      Test() : AProp( a_prop )  //set AProp to a_prop
        { 
          a_prop = 25; //set the initial vale of a_prop
        };

      Property<int> AProp; 
      
      void getProp( std::string s ) 
        { 
          std::cout << s << a_prop << std::endl << "\n";
        };
    };

int main()
  {
    Test test;

    test.getProp("a_prop Before: "); //a_prop = 25

    test.AProp = 32;

    test.getProp( "a_prop After: " ); //a_prop = 32
    
    int A = test.AProp;
    std::cout << A << std::endl;
  }
```